# Calculating time duration in decimal days using R, with missing dates in the time series

Tags: r, datetime, time-series, missing-data, duration

I have some animal tracking data of which I need to calculate the total number of **decimal days** each individual was tracked.

My data is in the following format, with animal id, x and y coordinates for location fixes and datetime for when the individual was found. The time zone is Eastern Standard Time (GMT-5).

```
id  x       y       datetime
1   291693  1977345 2019-05-16 10:07:00
2   291693  1977345 2019-05-17 11:23:00
3   291693  1977345 2019-05-18 13:28:00
4   291693  1977456 2019-05-24 12:48:00
5   291693  1977675 2019-06-01 10:51:00
```

My date and time as you can see is in yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss format.

My question is - which is the simplest way in R to calculate the total duration between datetimes *excluding* the missing dates & times between recorded location fixes?
Apologies if this is already been asked, I could find information on duration calculation but not with missing dates within this sort of time series specifically, but I imagine the answer is fairly straightforward!

*also, I'm trying to work out how to incorporate stand alone dates, currently I'm working it out manually by looking at the time difference between the time located and the time of the location fix for the individual tracked before them on that specific date.